# TopShelf Service Not Executing

Tags: c#, topshelf

I'm trying to get a [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) service to execute.
At the moment I have just some test code to see if I could get the service to install.
So far I have been able to get the services `Start()` and execute when in debug mode.
From there I install the service, eg `ConsoleApp.exe Install`.
The Service will show in [Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-overview), however when I start the service, it doesn't do anything, eg at the moment I have it creating a txt file on my desktop, which it does when using Visual Studio, however when I start the service from services, it wont.

Here is what I have so far.

 First I create the `Service Class`

```
class FooService
{
    public void Start()
    {
        string DESKTOP = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string Foo = "foo.txt";
        string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(DESKTOP, Foo);
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service Stopped");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm just creating a txt file on the desktop (which works in VS).
From there I configure the service.

```
internal static class ConfigureService
{
    internal static void Config(string serviceName, string serviceDescription)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName) | string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceDescription))
        {
            return;
        }

        HostFactory.Run(Config =>
        {
            Config.Service<FooService>(service =>
            {
                service.ConstructUsing(s => new FooService());
                service.WhenStarted(s => s.Start()); // start event.
                service.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop()); // stop event.  
            });

            // Create Event.
            Config.RunAsLocalSystem(); // user.
            Config.SetServiceName(serviceName); // service name.
            Config.SetDescription(serviceDescription); // service description.
        });
    }
}
```

And finally I execute it with the following;

```
// Entry Point.
static void Main()
{
    ConfigureService.Config("Foo Service", "some discription....Idk");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When starting the service, it says it `Running` however the file text file isn't appearing on the desktop.

Comment: The text file isn't appearing on your desktop as the service doesn't run under your account! Try a hard-coded path (that the account the service runs under has access to)

Comment: Thanks @stuartd That has done the trick! so if that wasn't the correct path, where would have that file been doing to?

Comment: I believe the service account has it's own 'desktop' but I have no idea where it's located. You could write the result of `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` to the test file and find out?

Comment: Thank you again!